# QObject::connect simply “rejects” my object at compile-time(!)

Tags: c++, qt

C is a QObject derived class, I can use it successfully.

I get a compilation error on the “connect”. If i’d change “this->controller”, to “this”, on the target, it will work fine. Something about the this->controller as the recipient causes this not to compile. I realize it must be something stupid, but the cause evades me...

```
MyClass::MyClass(C * controller)
    : QThread(NULL)
{
    this->controller = controller;
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(OnResponse(ResponseClass*)), this->controller, SLOT(OnResponse(ResponseClass*)));  // <---- "Compiler error: " error: no matching function for call to...."
}
```

Comment: What is the declaration of this->controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MY bad. The class of "this->controller" was declared with a forward declaration only due to circular referencing of *.h files. That caused the problem. Not much the compiler could do with it.